# Adding the Source Repo to CentOS 5

Tags: linux, centos

How and what repository do I add/enable that contains all of the source file packages in CentOS 5?

This is in order to enable `yumdownloader --source <package_name>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the source repo definitions are not included. Add the following as `/etc/yum.repos.d/Centos-Source.repo`:

```
[base-source]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base Source
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/SRPMS/
enabled=0

[updates-source]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates Source
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/SRPMS/
enabled=0

[addons-source]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Addons Source
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/addons/SRPMS/
enabled=0

[extras-source]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras Source
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/SRPMS/
enabled=0

[centosplus-source]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus Source
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/SRPMS/
enabled=0

[contrib-source]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib Source
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/SRPMS/
enabled=0
```

Comment: FTR: http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=1646

Comment: Unfortunately, source rpms seem to have disappeared from http://mirrors.centos.org and are now only on http://vault.centos.org .

Answer (score 0):

Marked Ignacio's answer as correct, but I ended up using the following before I saw the answer:

```
[base-SRPMS]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base SRPMS
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/SRPMS/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1
enabled=1

#released updates
[update-SRPMS]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates SRPMS
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/SRPMS/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1
enabled=1
```